# How can I configure size limits on Exchange Server 2003?

Tags: exchange-2003

I have a group of users in Active Directory called, Juniors. I'd like to limit the size a Juniors mailbox can have to a maximum of 20Megabytes. Meaning they can only have 20megabytes to store all their email on.

How can I set this up?

I'd also like Juniors to only be able to send a mails of maximum size of 50kilobytes.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look on the Exchange General/Advanced tabs on the users accounts, or you can set it on the information store.

Sadly I don't know of a way you can apply the setting to a group of users, it seems to be per-user, or per-database.

Comment: +1 - This is correct. The only way to do limits on a "per group" basis would be to co-locate all the common mailboxes in a single mailbox database and put limits on that database. Otherwise it's per-user limits.

Comment: I would recommend creating a new database for your Juniors, if you haven't already.  Then you can apply the settings at the database level as Hutch says.

Comment: @Holocryptic: Do you have a guide on how to create a new database for my Juniors?

Comment: @Sergio http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821748.  Look at the part at creating a new mailbox store.  Once you have the store created, under the properties for the store, set the limits for the mailboxes.  Then you need to move the Juniors mailboxes to the new store through the Exchange Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame that E2K3 Mailbox storage limits cannot be filtered like recipient policies.  In this instance I would create a VBS script to set the user's limits in AD, based on their group membership.